# Circliful plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I use [this plugin](https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful) in my app. Almost everything is fine, except one thing - after making a bigger radius, the progress bar is not shown properly. A bigger radius was made by this code:

```
$('#circle').find('circle').attr('r', 90);
$('#circle').find('.border').attr('stroke-dasharray', 0);
```

And now the progress bar is broken, the value is 100%, but the bar is filled only to nearly 66%. What can be the issue? Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why cause the issue is "[stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)".

Because the length of stroke-dasharray does not get bigger with "r" , when circle is bigger, its stroke length is unchanged.

The stroke-dasharray of first circle you set is totally fine.

### The problem is at the second circle.

Since the "r"(radius) increased, its circumference is longer.But the second circle stroke-dasharray is still (162, 20000) which 162 is length of stroke.

There are two ways to solve the issue.

The first one is the easy one. Take your case for example :

```
$('#circle').width('number') #number is  how big you want for circle
```

Circle change proportionally with the width of its wrapper, so you do not worry about stroke length.

---

The second one is a little bit complex.

```
big_circle = 90(new raidus)*3.14( which is π )*percent( in your case is 100% )
$('#circle').find('circle').attr('r', 90);
$('#circle').find('.border').attr('stroke-dasharray', 0);
$('#circle').find('.circle').attr('stroke-dasharray', 'big_circle, 20000');
```

If circliful can not calculate the new circumference, we do it ourself.

Hope these information is useful.

Comment: The second option works like dream. Thanks for this, you just saved me hours and hours.